# Expected value of cumulative distribution function(indicator functions, measure theory)

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

I have a function:

$F(x)={x^2}1_{(0,1/2)}(x) + {1 \over 2}1_{(1/2,2)}(x) + 1_{[2, \infty)}(x)$

where $1$ is indicator function.

I know that, expactation is equal to $E(X) = (\int_{0}^{\infty} 1 - F(x)) dx$

But how do we calculate integral above? Because it seems, that for example

$\int_{2}^{\infty} 1_{[2, \infty)}(x) dx = x|_2^{\infty}$ which is equal to infinity. Am I right?

Comment: If you want to use that result, then the correct formulation for expectation is $E(X)=\int_0^\infty (1-F(x))\,\mathrm{d}x$ for a non-negative continuous rv $X$.

Comment: @StubbornAtom thank you! But can you provide an example(different one), how can we calculate expected value of given distribution function?

Comment: You are calculating expected value of the random variable $X$, not the distribution function of $X$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Observe that
$$
1 - F(x) = (1-x^2)\mathsf 1_{\left(0,\frac12\right)}+\frac12\mathsf 1_{\left[\frac12,2\right]},
$$
and hence
\begin{align}
\mathbb E[X] &= \int_0^\infty (1-F(x))\ \mathsf dx\\
&= \int_0^{\frac12}(1-x^2)\ \mathsf dx + \int_{\frac12}^2\frac12\ \mathsf dx\\
&= \frac{11}{24} + \frac34\\
&= \frac{29}{24}.
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you for your comment:

Few questions:

1)About $1 - F(x)$: you subtracted it only fot the first interva (0;1/2). Why only from the first interval?

2)Calculations are clear. But for example in my example last term is equal to $x|_2^{\infty}$. basicaly it takes value infinity. Is it correct, or something I misunderstood?

Comment: Or why did you skip the last part of function?

Comment: $$\large 1 - 1 = \mathrm ?$$

Comment: @vitsuk The term ''$x|_2^\infty$'' never arises. Do you see that $E(X)=\int_0^{1/2}(1-x^2)\,\mathrm{d}x+\int_{1/2}^2(1-\frac{1}{2})\,\mathrm{d}x+\int_2^\infty(1-1)\,\mathrm{d}x$?